# Can't create table if including the file in main script

Tags: php, database, wordpress, plugins

I want to create a table by including the script that creates it in the main plugin file.

I have this:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'vkrwps_agt' );
function vkrwps_agt() {
   global $wpdb;
   global $jal_db_version;

   $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "attribute_groups";

   $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  attribute_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  attribute_group VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY id (id)
    );";

   require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
   dbDelta( $sql );

} // end vkrwps_agt()
```

If I have that in my main plugin file, it works (it creates the table), but I put that code in another script called `tables.php` inside `inc` folder in my plugin root directory, because I want to include it within the main plugin file.

I tried the following but it does not work:

```
require 'inc/tables.php';
```

I get no error (e.g. file not found) but the table does not get created.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in `register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'vkrwps_agt' );` you point to the current file (i.e. the plugin's main file, notice the `__FILE__`).

The function `register_activation_hook()` expects the **path to the main plugin file inside the wp-content/plugins directory**. A full path will work also.

For example, when the plugin is located in `wp-content/plugin/sampleplugin/sample.php`, then the name of this hook will become `activate_sampleplugin/sample.php`.

When the plugin consists of only one file and is (as by default) located at `wp-content/plugin/sample.php` the name of this hook will be `activate_sample.php`.

This function is a wrapper for the `activate_PLUGINNAME` action, and is easier to use.

Read the documentation [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook).